# Automated fill in columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe (shown below) where there are some asterisks in the "sig" column.
[image]

I want to fill in asterisks in the empty cells in the sig column everywhere above the furthest down row where there is an asterisk, which in this case would be everywhere from row "H" up to get something like this:

[image]

I'm thinking some sort of a for loop where it identifies the furthest down row where there is an asterisk and then fills in asterisks in empty cells above might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to code this.

For debugging purposes, I make the data frame in R with

```
df<- data.frame("variable"= c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"),
                "value" = c(0.04,0.03,0.04,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.01,0.04,0.1,0.02), 
                "sig" = c("*","*","*","","*","*","","*","","",""))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
df[1:max(which(df$sig == "*")), "sig"] = "*"
```

Gives:

```
   variable value sig
1         a  0.04   *
2         b  0.03   *
3         c  0.04   *
4         d  0.02   *
5         e  0.03   *
6         f  0.02   *
7         g  0.02   *
8         h  0.01   *
9         i  0.04    
10        j  0.10    
11        k  0.02
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `replace` based on finding the index of the last element having `*`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(sig = replace(sig, seq(tail(which(sig == "*"), 1)), "*"))
```

-output

```
df
   variable value sig
1         a  0.04   *
2         b  0.03   *
3         c  0.04   *
4         d  0.02   *
5         e  0.03   *
6         f  0.02   *
7         g  0.02   *
8         h  0.01   *
9         i  0.04    
10        j  0.10    
11        k  0.02
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be using `fill`, but you need to change `""` to `NA`

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
df <-
  data.frame("variable"= c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"),
             "value" = c(0.04,0.03,0.04,0.02,0.03,0.02,0.02,0.01,0.04,0.1,0.02), 
             "sig" = c("*","*","*","","*","*","","*","","",""))
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(sig = if_else(sig == "",NA_character_,sig)) %>% 
  fill(sig,.direction = "up")
```

### Output

```
   variable value  sig
1         a  0.04    *
2         b  0.03    *
3         c  0.04    *
4         d  0.02    *
5         e  0.03    *
6         f  0.02    *
7         g  0.02    *
8         h  0.01    *
9         i  0.04 <NA>
10        j  0.10 <NA>
11        k  0.02 <NA>
```